# Converting row values into ColumnName

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

**Table:** `SampleTbl`

```
 Values    Name
---------------------
23          id
33          b_id
2014-12-10  Date
55          t_id
NULL        p_id
NULL        comments
24            id
34           b_id
2014-12-11   Date
56           t_id
NULL         p_id
NULL        comments
```

**Expected Result:**

```
id     b_id     Date       t_id    p_id  comments
 ------------------------------------------------------
 23       33    2014-12-10    55    NULL  NULL
 24       34    2014-12-10    56    NULL  NULL
```

I have tried using `PIVOT`,

```
SELECT * FROM 
SampleTbl
Pivot (MIN ([Values]) FOR Name IN ([id],[b_id],[Date],[t_id],[p_id],[comments])) piv
```

**Result I Get:**

```
id     b_id     Date       t_id    p_id   comments
---------------------------------------------------
23      33     2014-12-10   55      NULL    NULL
```

but i din't get the expected result. Help me to get the result.

Comment: Should this be generic, or a once off?

Comment: What is your try so for??

Comment: @veera: Mr. Veera I have tried using Pivot, but i din't get the result.

Comment: @Kumar: Do you have any other column in your table? To identify 23, 33, 55 are from a single group?

Comment: @Kumar: You should have. Otherwise, how do you get the details of a single group? Like id,b_id,etc.? I mean, there is no relation between each fields of a record.

Comment: What result do you actually get?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: I added the result in the question.

Comment: How do you guarantee that the records are returned in the right order to get the result you want? If you don't specify an order by SQL Server can return them in any arbitrary order.

Comment: You have a big problem.  SQL tables represent unordered sets.  Hence, there is no ordering and no obvious way to combine "adjacent" rows into a record.  Do you have another column that can be used to combine the value or to identify groups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Use `window function` to get the result.

```
SELECT [id],[b_id],[Date],
       [t_id],[p_id],[comments]
FROM   (SELECT Row_number()OVER(partition BY name ORDER BY [values]) rn,*
        FROM   SampleTbl) A
       PIVOT (Min ([Values])
             FOR Name IN ([id],[b_id],[Date],
                          [t_id],[p_id],[comments])) piv
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d0e3b/1)

Comment: This only works if the values in each group are always smaller than the values in the next group. If not, the groups will be mixed up. Make a little change in the values introduced in your fiddle, and you'll see what I mean.